# Why the Sages said Halachot in their own name instead of their Rabbis?

Tags: halacha-theory, rabbis, authorship

The Gemmorah sets a rule - while saying a Halachah one should mention its [original] source (Megillah 16a):

> "אמר רבי אלעזר א"ר חנינא כל האומר דבר בשם אומרו מביא גאולה לעולם שנאמר ותאמר אסתר למלך בשם מרדכי"
>
> And Rabbi Elazar further said that Rabbi Ḥanina said: Whoever reports a saying in the name of he who said it brings redemption to the world.

The Halachot in the Mishnah and the Talmud are said in the name of the Tannayim and the Amorayim themselves (the end of the 2nd Temple), but not their ancestors.

Rambam in his Introduction to the Mishnah says that every Rabbi wrote the Halachot he heard from others to himself in his own collection, but, seemingly, everyone had to include the originator according to the Halachah above.

So, if there was a clear lineage of the Oral Torah tradition, why the Sages never mention their own sources, and it appears as if they "invented" the Halachot themselves?

Comment: There may be a simple answer to this. Sometimes you don't know who originated an adage, halacha, or other idea.

Comment: This question is only a question because of your added word "original". You've provided no support for that addition. -1. I recommend you edit in such support.

Comment: @msh210 I don't follow. What are you suggesting? Say we have a Machlokes of R"E and R"Y (R"H 10b) about the creation of the world - the G. brings their names, but who were the originators of the two schools?

Answer (score 5):

[Rambam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maimonides) addresses this in his letter to R. Pinchas the Judge:

**Shu"t HaRambam (Machon Yerushalayim) 2:538**

> דרך רבינו הקדוש תפשתי גם הוא עשה זו מלפני שכל סתם שאמר בלא שם אדם כלם
>   דברי חכמים אחרים הם ואותן החכמים האחרים לא מדעתן אמרו אלא מפי אחרים
>   ואחרים מאחרים עד משה רבינו **וכשם שלא הקפידו התנאים והאמוראים על שמות כל
>   החכמים שמימות משה עד ימיהם** שאין לדבר סוף כך לא נקפידו אנו על שמותם אם
>   הוזכרו או לא הוזכרו
>
> The way of Rabbeinu Hakadosh I have grasped. He too did this before me
>   – anything anonymous that he said without the name of a person is all
>   the words of other scholars. And those other scholars did not say this
>   from their own minds; rather, from the mouths of others and others
>   from others until Moses our teacher. And just like the tannaim and
>   amoraim were not careful about the names of all the scholars from the
>   days of Moses until their days, **because there would be no end to the
>   matter**, we also are not careful about their names whether they are
>   mentioned or not.

As you can see from the words that I bolded, it was simply impractical to quote everyone.

Comment: This answer does not explain why the Talmudic teaching in Megillah 16a was uttered at all.

Comment: @MauriceMizrahi Why it was uttered and why people didn't follow it are two distinct things.

Comment: Thank you,according to this explanation the Sages themselves didn't feel obligated to the Gemmorah's ruling in Megillah.